# rEFInd boot menu gone after updating Mac OS in a dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, mac, refind

I have a dual boot - Ubuntu 16.04 in my Macbook Pro. I updated my macOS from Yosemite to Big Sur and the rEFInd boot menu is gone. So, I am not able to login to my Ubuntu, where I have all my files. Many blogs ask me to reinstall rEFInd, which requires booting to macOS recovery mode to disable SIP. But, I do not have the firmware password to do so. Is it possible to restore the boot menu any other way? Or, is there any way to access my Ubuntu files? Please help!

[image: Disk Utility Image]

Comment: What year is your Mac? I ask because you have a Bios Boot Partition. You also a volume with the label `Recovery HD`. Usually the type would be `Apple_Boot`, but you have `Apple_HFS` instead. If this is a recovery partition, then the partition is not needed, since Big Sur's recovery is stored in the APFS volume with the identifier `disk1s3`.

Comment: It is a Macbook Pro from Mid 2014.

Comment: Are both OS installed as EFI or is one in Legacy Bios? You have a grub boot partition?

Comment: rEFInd should be still on your EFI volume, if you run something like `sudo diskutil mount EFI`, this should show you the EFI icon on your desktops with a rEFInd directory. It's likely your MacOS update has just set Mac as the primary boot option. You should be able to run the bless command to restore rEFInd.

Comment: I am not able to run the bless command due to the SIP active. I cannot disable it without booting from recovery. And I cannot boot from recovery as I do not have my firmware password @fyberoptik

Comment: @SasukeUchiha both are installed as EFI and yea I have a grub boot partition

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to reinstall Yosemite. You can then bless `rEFInd`. There are different ways to accomplish this. Below are the steps to one such way. Basically, you will be making a image of a Yosemite install in a virtual machine. Next, you will restore Yosemite to a new partition on your internal drive.

1. Make sure File Sharing is enabled for Big Sur. See the `Sharing` pane of the `System Preferences` application.
2. Download Yosemite from the Apple website [How to get old versions of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683). The file `InstallMacOSX.dmg` should download your `Downloads` folder.
3. Open the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file and install the `Install OS X Yosemite` application to the `Applications` folder.
4. Download [VMware Fusion Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal). This is a free product.
5. Install VMware Fusion Player
6. Install Yosemite in a virtual machine. Open the `VMware Fusion` application and create a new virtual machine. Drag and drop the `Install OS X Yosemite` application from the `Applications` folder to the `VMware Fusion` application window shown below.

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN7Ow.png]

   Complete the installation of Yosemite.
7. Once booted to Yosemite, open the `Disk Utility` application and create a second partition. The new partition should to be at least 8 GB in size. Below is what I chose.

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTyCR.png]

   When finished, quit the `Disk Utility` application.
8. Open a `Terminal` application window and enter the command shown below.

   ```
   diskutil rename disk0s2 MyYosemite
   sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
   ```
9. Close all `Finder` application windows, quit all applications and restart the virtual machine. The machine will boot to OS X Recovery.
10. Open the `Disk Utility` application and highlight the `MyYosemite` volume. Select `New Image` and enter the following in the popup window, then select the `Save` button.

    [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAG4C.png]

    When finished, highlight the `MyYosemite.dmg` file, then select `Images`> `Scan Image for Restore` from the menu bar. When finish, restart the virtual machine. The machine will boot to Yosemite.
11. Connect to the Big Sur host and transfer the `MyYosemite.dmg` file from the `MyBackup` volume to your `Downloads` folder on the host.
12. Close all `Finder` application windows, quit all applications and shutdown the virtual machine.
13. If necessary, delete the virtual machine to make more space available.
14. Quit the `VMware Fusion` application.
15. Download the [latest rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). Currently this is version 0.12.0. The `refind-bin-0.12.0` folder should be created in your `Downloads` folder.
16. Open a `Terminal` application window and enter the command below. Basically, the APFS container is being shrunk by 25 GB to make a new partition for the Yosemite volume.

    ```
    diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 140.8G jhfs+ NewVolume 0
    ```

    Next, enter the commands below to install the Yosemite volume in the new partition.

    ```
    cd ~/Downloads
    diskutil unmount disk0s3
    sudo asr restore --source MyYosemite.dmg --target /dev/disk0s3 --erase
    diskutil mount disk0s3
    ```

    Finally, enter the commands below to transfer the `rEFInd` download to the Yosemite volume.

    ```
    xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine refind-bin-0.12.0
    mv refind-bin-0.12.0 /Volumes/MyYosemite/Users/Shared
    ```

    When finished close all `Finder` application windows and quit all applications.
17. Select to restart to `MyYosemite` from the `Startup Disk` pane of the `System Preferences` application.
18. Once booted to Yosemite, either bless or reinstall `rEFInd`. If reinstalling, you might want to first backup the `refind.conf` file, although the `rEFInd` installer will probably rename the existing `refind.conf` file to `refind.conf-sample`.

    > *I believe reinstalling is the safer alternative.*

    If `rEFInd` was installed using the default options, then the commands below will bless `rEFInd`.

    ```
    sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
    sudo bless --mount /Volumes/EFI --setBoot --file /Volumes/EFI/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi --shortform
    diskutil unmount disk0s1
    ```

    The command below will reinstall `rEFInd` using the default options.

    ```
    sudo /Users/Shared/refind-bin-0.12.0
    ```

If you have any questions, post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the lack of firmware password will stop you booting from a Ubuntu USB stick. If you can boot with a Ubuntu disk, you should be able to get around the Mac SIP securite by using the `efibootmgr` command to list out the efi boot option and then set the refind as the default option.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples